# Newtheorem lemma reference

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, newtheorem

I want to create lemmas with my own enumeration, e.g. Lemma A.1, A.2, ..., using `\newtheorem`. However, when compiled and referenced, the number is wrong for what seems a simple reason. LaTeX enumerates by section, but I want my own labeling "A.1" to carry over. How do I force that for any arbitrary labeling? My challenge us I have many such Lemma A.# in a section that cannot be section "A" for easy to explain but space consuming reasons.

Here is a working example of my dilemma. The referenced "Lemma A.1" comes as as Lemma B, but I need it to come out as "Lemma A.1".

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem*{lemmaA1}{Lemma A.1}

\begin{document}

\section{Stuff\label{app:stuff}}

\begin{lemmaA1}\label{lm:11}
We have that $1=1$.
\end{lemmaA1}

Lemma \ref{lm:11} is true.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to define a bunch of `\newtheorem`s for each key you need. Moreover, `\newtheorem*` defined environments don't set a counter, so `\label` inside them won't work and you'd get a random reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\genericname}{}
\newtheorem{generic}{\genericname}

\newenvironment{lemma*}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\genericname}{Lemma}%
  \renewcommand{\thegeneric}{#1}%
  \generic
}{\endgeneric}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma*}{A.1}\label{lm:11}
We have that $1=1$.
\end{lemma*}

Lemma~\ref{lm:11} is true.

\end{document}
```

You may defined other `generic` based environments.

[image]

Comment: That's perfect: thanks so much (I should have reached out about this years ago)!